# Morrie's Law Type Proving trigonometric identities

Tags: calculus

Morrie's formula is the following trigonometic identity

$$2^k \prod _{k=0}^{k-1} \cos \left(2^k z\right)=\frac{\sin \left(2^k\right)}{\sin (z)}$$

I've been working on the following formulae and it works fine,

$$2 z \sin \left(2^{n-1}\right) \csc \left(2^n z\right) \prod _{k=0}^{n-1} \sec \left(2^{k-1}\right) \cos \left(2^k z\right)=2 z \sin \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \csc (z)$$

$$\frac{\left(\cos \left(2^{n+\frac{1}{2}} z\right) \tan \left(2^{n+\frac{1}{2}} z\right)\right) \prod _{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{\cos \left(2^{k+\frac{1}{2}}\right)}{\cos \left(2^{k+\frac{1}{2}} z\right)}}{\cos \left(2^{n+\frac{1}{2}}\right) \tan \left(2^{n+\frac{1}{2}}\right)}=\csc \left(\sqrt{2}\right) \cos \left(\sqrt{2} z\right) \tan \left(\sqrt{2} z\right)$$

I have been trying to prove Morrie's formula using induction.

It is true for $n=1$:

$$\left\{\cos \left(\sqrt{2}\right) \csc \left(2 \sqrt{2}\right) \sin \left(2 \sqrt{2} z\right) \sec \left(\sqrt{2} z\right),\csc \left(\sqrt{2}\right) \sin \left(\sqrt{2} z\right)\right\}$$

It is true for $n=2$:

$$\left\{\cos \left(\sqrt{2}\right) \cos \left(2 \sqrt{2}\right) \csc \left(4 \sqrt{2}\right) \sin \left(4 \sqrt{2} z\right) \sec \left(\sqrt{2} z\right) \sec \left(2 \sqrt{2} z\right),\csc \left(\sqrt{2}\right) \sin \left(\sqrt{2} z\right)\right\}$$

But is it true for $n+1$?

Comment: What's your question?